# Ссылки в js файлах в AndriodStudio в компоненте Webview

Tags: android, android-studio

Делаю из сайта приложение через webview

простая структура:

```
index.html
  |
  | js / main.jx
  | tempate / test.html
```

в js файле есть такой код

```
app.request.get('template/test.html', function (data) { 
          alert('data);
});
```

При запуске в эмуляторе не находит этот файл (не делает запрос),
но если подставить полный путь:

```
app.request.get('https://mysity.com/template/test.html', function (data) { 
          alert('data);
});
```

То тогда работает.
Подскажите как правильно оформлять ссылки на локальные файлы, которые находятся в папке www при создании андроид приложения. Спасибо

Comment: Как загружаете первую страницу? И какой путь у этих файлов относительно проекта?

Comment: Загрузка первой страницы: web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html"); А путь как указал выше

Comment: Попробуйте полный `file:///android_asset/www/template/test.html`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, хотя я пробовал примерно так же, но что-то видимо не то вводил.

Comment: А может ты знаешь как решиьт проблемму сессии? При конвертации в приложение сессия не держится от php. (хотя в обычном браузере работает). В настройках стоит getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

Comment: Проверьте CORS хидеры состороны PHP https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS